# splitting by using & \qquad

Tags: spacing, formatting

```
\epsilon ^7 \left(g_7 \phi _1^7+6 g_6 \phi _1^5 \phi _2+10 g_5 \phi _1^3 \phi _2^2
+ 4 g_4 \phi _1 \phi _2^3+5 g_5 \phi _1^4 \phi _3+12 g_4 \phi _1^2 \phi _2 \phi _3 
+ 3 g_3 \phi _2^2 \phi _3+3 g_3 \phi _1 \phi _3^2+4 g_4 \phi _1^3 \phi _4
+ 6 g_3 \phi _1  \phi _2 \phi _4  +2 g_2 \phi _3 \phi _4+3 g_3 \phi _1^2 \phi _5
+ 2 g_2 \phi _2 \phi _5+2 g_2 \phi _1 \phi _6+\phi _7\right)
```

I need to split the above line and I did using & \qquad , but didn't run . I think the problem arised because, I used \ within bracket.

```
\epsilon ^7 \left(g_7 \phi _1^7+6 g_6 \phi _1^5 \phi _2+10 g_5 \phi _1^3 \phi _2^2 \\ 
& \qquad +4 g_4 \phi _1 \phi _2^3+5 g_5 \phi _1^4 \phi _3+12 g_4 \phi _1^2 \phi _2 \phi_3+\\
& \qquad3 g_3 \phi _2^2 \phi _3+3 g_3 \phi _1 \phi _3^2+4 g_4 \phi _1^3 \phi _4+6 g_3 \phi _1 \phi _2 \phi _4  + \\
& \qquad 2 g_2 \phi _3 \phi _4+3 g_3 \phi _1^2 \phi _5+2 g_2 \phi _2 \phi _5+2 g_2 \phi _1 \phi _6+\phi _7\right)
```

Comment: You can't use `\left / \right` with a line break between them.  Replace them by a pair `\bigl / \bigr` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out the `multline` environment of the `amsmath` package. It helps you formatting this kind of long equations. If you need to embed that into an `align` environment, the package `mathtools` provides the `multlined` environment which could be useful. Your specific example should work like this:

```
\begin{multline}
\epsilon ^7 \bigl(g_7 \phi _1^7+6 g_6 \phi _1^5 \phi _2+10 g_5 \phi _1^3 \phi _2^2 \\ 
+4 g_4 \phi _1 \phi _2^3+5 g_5 \phi _1^4 \phi _3+12 g_4 \phi _1^2 \phi _2 \phi_3\\
+3 g_3 \phi _2^2 \phi _3+3 g_3 \phi _1 \phi _3^2+4 g_4 \phi _1^3 \phi _4+6 g_3 \phi _1 \phi _2 \phi _4  \\
+2 g_2 \phi _3 \phi _4+3 g_3 \phi _1^2 \phi _5+2 g_2 \phi _2 \phi _5+2 g_2 \phi _1 \phi _6+\phi _7\bigr)
\end{multline}
```